How do manganese nodules in the ocean sustain oxygen production without depleting over geological time scales?
The news reports that manganese nodules on the ocean floor produce oxygen through electrochemical reactions. But how do these nodules sustain themselves without depleting? Do they replenish their manganese supply through ongoing precipitation? And if so, why haven't they grown enormous over millions of years?
Or the news doesn't makes sense?

Please avoid opinion-based (and especially political) comments within a question. This is a very interesting question (I had thought of asking similar based on encountering this news but did not get around to it) but the site is not suited for political discussions. You might take such discussions to one of our chatrooms.

They may very well have "depleted" during the experimental study, as oxygen levels tended to increase only by a finite amount over a limited time period (which varied from sample to sample), as illustrated in this figure taken from the reference 1 cited by the OP:

Thus nothing in the data should be construed as implying continuous oxygen production over long periods.
It is possible, given the variable oxidation states of transition metals, for the nodules to alternately produce oxygen and either remove oxygen or produce hydrogen from the water. But the reference does not explore this possibility.
Reference

Sweetman, A.K., Smith, A.J., de Jonge, D.S.W. et al. Evidence of dark oxygen production at the abyssal seafloor. Nat. Geosci. (2024). https://doi.org/10.1038/s41561-024-01480-8. [No volume, issue or page numbers were given in the citation link.]

